# How to build a has_many-alike association containing a list of various Models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an `Order` which has many `line_items`. Only this is not a `LineItem` module, but a list of "things that act Orderable". E.g. `Addon` or `Site`.

```
class Order
  attr_accessor :line_items
  before_save :persist_line_items

  private
  def persist_line_items
    @line_items.each {|li| li.save }
  end
end

class Addon
  belongs_to: order
end
class Site
  belongs_to: order
end
```

Which can be used as:

```
order = Order.new
order.line_items << Addon.new(order: order)
order.line_items << Site.new(order: order)
```

But, now I want to load an Order and join the "associated" line_items. I
could load them in an after_initialize hook, and do an
`Addon.find_by(order_id: self.id)` but that quickly leads to a lot of
queries; where a `JOIN` would be more appropriate. In addition, I
currently miss the validations trickling up: when a normal `has_many`
related item is invalid the containing model will not be valid either:

```
order = Order.new(line_items: [an_invalid_line_item])
order.valid? #=> false
```

I am wondering if there is a way
to leverage ActiveRecords' `has_many`-relation to be used with a list of
different models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) should do the trick.

Would look like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orderable, polymorphic: true
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, as: :orderable
end

class Addon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, as: :orderable
end
```

It would use a join table, but i think this is actually a good thing. Otherwise you could use STI for your `Addon` and `Site` models, but that would not make a lot of sense in my regard.

Comment: This does add a new Persisted model, though: LineItem. But that is not a huge issue. `STI` is not really an option, because Orderables are "Ductypes" and certainly don't qualify for subclasses ATM.